# Pointer to peripheral hardware as template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, stm32

I want to access STM32F0 peripheral register through C++ templates. A GPIO Port is defined as follows by vendor header file:

excerpt stm32f0xx.h

```
#define     __IO    volatile  //!< Defines 'read / write' permissions             

typedef struct
{
    __IO uint32_t MODER;        
    __IO uint16_t OTYPER;       
    uint16_t RESERVED0;         
    __IO uint32_t OSPEEDR;      
    __IO uint32_t PUPDR;        
    __IO uint16_t IDR;          
    uint16_t RESERVED1;         
    __IO uint16_t ODR;          
    uint16_t RESERVED2;         
    __IO uint32_t BSRR;         
    __IO uint32_t LCKR;         
    __IO uint32_t AFR[2];       
    __IO uint16_t BRR;          
    uint16_t RESERVED3;         
} GPIO_TypeDef;

#define PERIPH_BASE           ((uint32_t)0x40000000)
#define AHB2PERIPH_BASE       (PERIPH_BASE + 0x08000000)

#define GPIOA_BASE            (AHB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x00000000)

#define GPIOA               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOA_BASE)
```

I created a template class for output handling.

main.cpp:

```
template <uintptr_t port, uint8_t pin>
class Output {
public:
    static void set() {
        GPIO_TypeDef *castedPort = reinterpret_cast<GPIO_TypeDef *>(port);
        castedPort->ODR = (1 << pin);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Output<GPIOA_BASE, 5>::set();

    while(1)
    {
    }
}
```

This code runs fine, if I compile it with launchpad g++ for arm. But I want to test my code
with GoogleTest, so I made a test for it and tried to compile it.

intArgument.cpp:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

typedef struct {
    /* see above definition */
} GPIO_TypeDef;

uint32_t gpioa[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

template <uintptr_t port, int pin>
class Output {
public:
  static void set() {
    GPIO_TypeDef * castedPort = reinterpret_cast<GPIO_TypeDef *>(port);
    castedPort->ODR = (1 << pin);
  }
};

TEST(OutputTest, OutputDataRegisterWritten) {
  Output<gpioa, 5>::set();
  GPIO_TypeDef * port = reinterpret_cast<GPIO_TypeDef *>(gpioa);
  EXPECT_EQ((1 << 5), port->ODR);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

But now compile fails. A cast to a int via `reinterpret_cast` is not allowed, because then it is no more a constant expression.

```
fabian@ubuntu:~/workspace/stackOverflowQuestion$ g++ -std=c++11 intArgument.cpp -lgtest -pthread -o intptrArgument.out
intArgument.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void OutputTest_OutputDataRegisterWritten_Test::TestBody()’:
intArgument.cpp:23:18: error: conversion from ‘uint32_t* {aka unsigned int*}’ to ‘long unsigned int’ not considered for non-type template argument
   Output<gpioa, 5>::set();
                  ^
intArgument.cpp:23:18: error: could not convert template argument ‘gpioa’ to ‘long unsigned int’
intArgument.cpp:23:26: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
    Output<gpioa, 5>::set();
```

So i tried to change type of `port` to `GPIO_TypeDef *`.

pointerArgument.cpp:

```
typedef struct {
    /* see above definition */
} GPIO_TypeDef;

GPIO_TypeDef gpioa;

// using GPIO_TypeDef * as template argument
template <GPIO_TypeDef * port, int pin>
class Output {
public:
  static void set() {
    port->ODR = (1 << pin);
  }
};

TEST(OutputTest, OutputDataRegisterWritten) {
  Output<&gpioa, 5>::set();
  EXPECT_EQ((1 << 5), gpioa.ODR);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

It compiled and test is passed.

```
fabian@ubuntu:~/workspace/stackOverflowQuestion$ g++ -std=c++11 pointerArgument.cpp -lgtest -pthread -o pointerArgument.out
fabian@ubuntu:~/workspace/stackOverflowQuestion$ ./test.out 
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from OutputTest
[ RUN      ] OutputTest.OutputDataRegisterWritten
[       OK ] OutputTest.OutputDataRegisterWritten (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from OutputTest (1 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

But using this approach is failing for the arm compiler:

main.cpp

```
template <GPIO_TypeDef * port, uint8_t pin>
class Output {
public:
    static void set() {
        port->ODR = (1 << pin);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Output<GPIOA, 5>::set();

    while(1)
    {
    }
}

compiler error:
[cc] main.cpp:13:17: error: '1207959552u' is not a valid template argument for 'GPIO_TypeDef*' because it is not the address of a variable
[cc] main.cpp:13:25: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
```

I understand both errors, but is there any way to get this work? I searched for compiler flags, but did not find
any, that might change this behaviour. A `#define TESTING` combined with `#ifdef/#ifndef` might work, but I dont
like it, because then tested code differs from produced code. Perhaps there is a nicer solution?

Used Compilers:

```
g++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev3, Built by MinGW-W64 project), 4.9-2014q4 by Launchpad for STM32F0XX
g++ (Ubuntu 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) 4.9.2 for Testing
```

Comment: Using the pointer template, try `Output<GPIOA, 1>` instead of `Output<GPIOA_BASE, 1>`. It's hard to figure out what is going on here because you haven't shown a complete code sample; you've shown pieces and left it up to us to string them together, in some cases omitting important information.  Please put together a **complete** sample of each approach showing exactly on which line(s) the failure occurs in each case.

Comment: I used GPIOA as pointer parameter, but this results in the last error. Will give more detailed information tomorrow.

Comment: A template parameter must be initialized with a constant expression, which cannot contain `reinterpret_cast`s. Thus you can't use a pointer template parameter with a hardcoded address cast to a pointer, nor an integer template parameter with a pointer cast to an integer. Possibly, you can do `template<class PortType, PortType port, int pin> class Output { /*...*/};` and then `Output<uintptr_t, GPIOA_BASE, 5>` and `Output<GPIO_TypeDef *, &gpioa, 5>`.

Comment: With this approach tested code would differ from production code, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With linker flag `Wl,section-start` you can define the start address of a specified section. So first I forced my register mocks to be in a own section:

```
GPIO_TypeDef gpioa __attribute__((section(".myTestRegisters")));
GPIO_TypeDef gpiob __attribute__((section(".myTestRegisters")));
```

Also I defined `const uintptr_t` address values for section start and each register.

```
const uintptr_t myTestRegisterSectionAddress = 0x8000000;
const uintptr_t gpioaAddress = myTestRegisterSectionAddress;
const uintptr_t gpiobAddress = myTestRegisterSectionAddress + sizeof(GPIO_TypeDef);
```

These values I can use as template parameter.

```
template <uintptr_t port, int pin>
class Output {
public:
    static void set() {
        GPIO_TypeDef * castedPort = reinterpret_cast<GPIO_TypeDef *>(port);
        castedPort->ODR = (1 << pin);
    }
};

TEST(OutputTest, OutputDataRegisterWritten) {
    Output<gpioaAddress, 5>::set();
    EXPECT_EQ(1 << 5, gpioa.ODR);

    Output<gpiobAddress, 10>::set();
    EXPECT_EQ(1 << 10, gpiob.ODR);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

To force a start address for a section you can use `Wl,-section-start=.{sectionName}={startAddress}`.

So in my case I use:

```
g++ intArgument.cpp -std=c++11 -g -o intArgument.out -lgtest -pthread -Wl,-section-start=.myTestRegisters=0x8000000
```

Running application results in:

```
fabian@ubuntu:~/workspace/stackOverflowQuestion$ ./intArgument.out 
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from OutputTest
[ RUN      ] OutputTest.OutputDataRegisterWritten
[       OK ] OutputTest.OutputDataRegisterWritten (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from OutputTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

And a objdump shows following information:

```
fabian@ubuntu:~/workspace/stackOverflowQuestion$ objdump -S -j .myTestRegisters intArgument.out 

intArgument.out:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .myTestRegisters:

0000000008000000 <gpioa>:
        ...

000000000800000c <gpiob>:
```

This works not with optimizations because the elements can be swapped.